# In a package, how to call a R function from this package with Rcpp?

Tags: r, package, rcpp

The **Rcpp** quick reference guide shows how to call a R function from a package in a Rcpp code. It takes as example the **stats** package. But if I do a package and I want to call a R function from this package with Rcpp, also in this package, how should I do? I didn't try, but I guess that following the **stats** example, simply replacing **stats** with **mypackage**, will not work because **mypackage** does not exist yet during the compilation. I hope my English phrasing is clear...

Comment: I cannot think of an example where a call is made into the same package, for the 'circular reference' problem you mention.  (Unless of course I am overlooking _exactly_ what you are asking...)  So I think to be safe you may need a dependency package you can ensure exists when you build your package.

Comment: I just had a quick test of this and it seems that this, circular reference, still seems to work

Comment: My hunch was wrong, and @user20650 was right. I can post a quick example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set up a quick package `tstpkg` via a call to [`kitten.r`](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/kitten.r) using the [pkgKitten](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=pkgKitten) package.

I added this R function:

```
theAnswer <- function() { 42L }
```

and indeed we can call it from the same package *simply by not prefixing any namespace etc* as in

```
#include <Rcpp/Light>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool checkAnswer() {
    Rcpp::Function f("theAnswer");
    int val = Rcpp::as<int>(f());
    return val == 42;
}
```

A quick ad-hoc call on the command-line confirms:

```
$ Rscript -e 'library(tstpkg); theAnswer(); checkAnswer()'
[1] 42
[1] TRUE
$
```

Comment: *Remarks:* 1) the R function must be exported; 2) if the package **tstpkg** is not loaded, `tstpkg::checkAnswer()` will not work (R function `theAnswer` not found).

Comment: Yes of course as this is true for every R package. Note also that I said I used `pkgKitten::kitten` which creates a NAMESPACE containing the standard wildcard `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")`.  In any event I switched to commiting my answers so you can find the [full package `tstpkg` here](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/stackoverflow/tree/master/76038026/tstpkg).